# Using setCursorPosition in PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I currently have a hidden QWidget, which contains a QLineEdit

Upon showing that hidden QWidget, I want the cursor to be on the QLineEdit. Any help with implementation?

This class is shown when a button is clicked in an earlier class

```
    class showInfo(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(showInfo, self).__init__(parent)

            showName = QtGui.QLabel("Name of Show:")
            self.showNameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            self.showNameEdit.setCursorPosition(0) #THIS SHOULD WORK

            self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.showNameEdit)

            self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
```

Answer (score 3):

try calling [`self.showNameEdit.setFocus()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#setFocus)